# Переменная отображается как null

Tags: javascript

> Не видит переменную list

```
new_input.addEventListener("keydown", function keypress(key){

if (key.keyCode == "13") {
    second_p.innerHTML = new_input.value;
    let hide = document.getElementById('new_input');

    hide.style.display = 'none';

    let add = document.createElement('input');
    add.id = 'second_input';
    second_div.appendChild(add);

    let third_div = document.createElement('div');
    third_div.id = 'third_div';
    container.appendChild(third_div);

    let third_input = document.createElement('input');
    third_input.id = 'third_input';
    third_input.placeholder = 'add a list';
    third_div.appendChild(third_input);
};

let list = document.getElementById(second_input);
console.log(list);
```

Comment: А что такое second_input?

Comment: id inputа, заданного в переменной add

Answer (score 1):

```
let list = document.getElementById('second_input');
```

И вызывать это надо *после* выполнения обработчика.